# setTimeout callback gets "random number" as parameter?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Today, I was making a loop with a setTimeout(). Unfortunately, some function parameters were getting strange values.

In short, this is what's happening:

```
var x = 1;
var steps = 3;
var timer = false;

function myFunc( y ){
   if( !isNaN(y)&&parseInt(y)==y&&y>0 ) { // if y is int and greater than 0
     x = y;
   } else { // y is no int or is below 0
     if( x >= steps ) { // x is greater than or equal to steps, return to first step
      x = 1
     } else { // x is less than steps, add 1
      x++;
     }
   }

   window.clearTimeout( timer );

   timer = setTimeout( myFunc, 1000 );
}
```

Now, somehow Mr. Firefox is randomly throwing an int, far greater than "steps" into the "y" parameter while triggering the timer... WHY does it do that?

I've resolved this problem by simple doing this:

```
timer = setTimeout( function(){ myFunc( -1 ) }, 1000 );
```

But still... WHY was the browser giving random numbers in the "y" parameter?

Anyone?

Comment: What did you expect that "y" would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox will call the function with the number of milliseconds "late" the function is in executing.

Comment: So that's what it's been doing all along xD It could have just told me! Thank you very much sir, for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As a protip, you can also just use `setInterval` to achieve the same basic functionality:

```
var x = 1;
var steps = 3;
var timer = false;

function myFunc( y ){
    if (parseFloat(y) == parseInt(y) && !isNaN(y) && y > 0) {
        x = y;
    } else if (x >= steps) {
        x = 1;
    } else {
        x++;
    }
}


timer = window.setInterval(function() { 
    myFunc(1); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Not really a protip, the timeout i'm using is dynamically changed every now and then. But that's not what this is about ;)

Comment: I also subtly modified your conditional statements. :) I'd still prefer using setInterval from outside of the function as it feels a little cleaner and is slightly more adaptable, but that's a "feeling" thing.

Comment: Didn't ask for that, but since you did, let me explain why I didnt: I added some nice comments so people who don't understand js at all can enjoy the question ;)

Comment: Well, then you might just rate my post as usefull because I did :P Nah just kidding ;) Thx for helping anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Gecko passes an extra parameter
>   to the callback routine, indicating
>   the "lateness" of the timeout in
>   milliseconds.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax

Infinite loop?

```
var x = 0,
steps = 3,
timer = false;

(function myFunc(y)
{
    x = y % steps;

    timer = setTimeout(myFunc, 1000, ++x);
})(0);
```